# How to get foreign address of oracle database background processes in Solaris

Tags: process, solaris

I use the `sudo netstat -ntap` command in linux to get the details (including PID, local and foreign address) of foreground and background processes started by oracle database such as `tnslsnr`, `ora_pmon_*`. How can I do the same in Solaris either using `netstat` or `lsof`?

Comment: What do you mean by  foreign address? IP address?

Comment: What have you done so far in Solaris, and what version of it are you running?

Comment: I use both 10 and 11 of Solaris. Happy to get separate methods for both. In solaris I tried both netstat -a and lsof -i TCP

Comment: Ninov - foreign address is same as remote address. In linux netstat shows the heading as foreign address and solaris shows it as remote address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't note the version of Solaris that you're using.

If you're using v11, netstat supports a -u option which will give you want you want:

solaris11  [8] `netstat -u`

TCP: IPv4

Local Address        Remote Address      User     Pid     Command     Swind  Send-Q  Rwind  Recv-Q    State

...

...

...

Prior versions would require building lsof, or using dtrace on v10.  If you supply your version and arch of Solaris, someone is more likely to give you a specific answer.

Comment: I use both 10 and 11. Let us take as test case 11.3. I have tried multiple combinations of parameters using netstat and lsof .. but am not able to make ora_pmon_* show up (this is a background process). I am getting tnslsnr. Pl help specifically with respect to ora_pmon_*